# How to stock result of mysqli into an associative array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

In order to setup a REST API for my android app, i would like to get an associative array from the following statement :

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores_diag WHERE rim = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count=$stmt->num_rows();
    echo $count;
```

This request should return 3 result and the $count is good, i have my 3 result. However how could i process to stock the result into an array in which i could navigate like this :

$array[0]["name"] = Name of the first item

$array[1]["name"] = Name of the Second item

This is for encoding the array into json for my api.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function you are looking for:

Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

You can use it like

```
mysqli_fetch_all($stmt,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You must have mysqlnd driver and php 5.3 or above. If you cannot run the function try using

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores_diag WHERE rim = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$fetchAsssoc = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fetchAsssoc[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($fetchAsssoc);
//$stmt->store_result();
//$count=$stmt->num_rows();
//echo $count;
```

End in the end you can return/echo `json_encode($assocArray);`

Comment: Im a bit confused, shoud i use it like this ?  

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores_diag WHERE rim = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count=$stmt->num_rows();
        echo $count;
        $result = mysqli_fetch_all($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $result[0]["name"];

Cause i have no result display at all when i do this ?

Comment: Do you have mysqlnd driver installed and is your php 5.3 or above ?

Comment: i dont know, how shoud i check this ?

My code is working on a server and im testing with postman

Comment: $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores_diag WHERE rim = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $assocArray = $array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
            echo 'test';
            $assocArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($assocArray);


Nothing is print, not even "test", even when i try $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120096/discussion-between-hugo-houyez-and-g9m29).